# Can I see the contents of Core Data managed objects in the stack variables area?

Tags: ios

I'm developing for iOS 6.1 and I'm learning Core Data.

I've got a managed object abc.myString that I've stuffed a string into:

```
abc.myString = @"the String";
```

When I see abc.myString in the variables area, if I look inside, I see only NSManagedObject and if I drill deeper, I see a lot of stuff I don't understand but I don't see my string.

But, after loading abc.myString, I can do this to verify what I put in:

```
NSLog( @"contents = %@", abc.myString );
```

Is this expected behavior; that I cannot see into abc.myString in the variables area?

Comment: Benedict Cohen's answer covers it, but if you want to log a more readable message, you can overide the `- (NSString *)description` method in a category that returns `self.myString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. `NSManagedObject` doesn't store its' fields in instances variables. Think of `NSManagedObject` as a front end to the persistent store's data. `NSManagedObject` doesn't actually store the data it fetches and update the persistent store.

You can still access the data by using the debugger. In the console type the follow to log an object:

`po variableNameOrAddressOfTheObjectYouWantToLog`

You can also set up break points to do this logging automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Xcode will not display the contents of the managed object in the variables list, but you can right click & use `Print Description of 'xyz'` to print the contents into the console.